# How to fetch conditional Deserialization xml list in c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I want to fetch data from deserialize xml list with some condition. But I did not get any proper solution for that. Below is my code snippet:

```
 public List<LinkInfo> GetLinks(string entityType, string relatedEntityType, string linkType)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Project));
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\\SampleMetaData.xml");
            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

            Project xmlData = (Project)obj;
            return xmlData.Module.Links.Link.Select(field => new LinkInfo
            {
                EntityId = field.EntityId,
                EntityType = field.EntityType,
                RelatedEntityId = field.RelatedEntityId,
                RelatedEntityType = field.RelatedEntityType,
                LinkType = field.LinkType
            }).ToList();             
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in",ex);
            throw;
        }
       
    }
```

Below is my XML file format:

```
    <Links>
        <Link EntityId="5" EntityType="Doors_Module1"  RelatedEntityId="7" RelatedEntityType="Doors_Module2" LinkType="InLink"/>
        <Link EntityId="6" EntityType="Doors_Module1"  RelatedEntityId="8" RelatedEntityType="Doors_Module2" LinkType="InLink"/>
        <Link EntityId="7" EntityType="Doors_Module1"  RelatedEntityId="9" RelatedEntityType="Doors_Module2" LinkType="External"/>
    </Links>
```

I want to fetch like **`where LinkType="Inlink" EntityType="Doors_Module1" and RelatedEntityType="Doors_Module2"`**

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you are using xml class serialization right?
In that case you can simple use `.Where(x=>x.LinkType == 'Doors_Module1')`

Comment: Can you please share the LinkInfo class too?

Comment: for dynamic object you can use foreach or for loop `obj.[i].LinkType` kind off

Comment: And the Project class while you're at it

Comment: @FıratÇağlarAkbulut I think he is using dynamic object instead of class

Comment: Thanks @ArijitMukherjee, but I dont get proper output....would you plz send me code snippet

Comment: hi mayur tell me

Comment: what output are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
return xmlData.Module.Links.Link
.Where(x=>.LinkType == 'Inlink' && x.EntityType == 'Doors_Module1')
.Select(field => new LinkInfo
        {
            EntityId = field.EntityId,
            EntityType = field.EntityType,
            RelatedEntityId = field.RelatedEntityId,
            RelatedEntityType = field.RelatedEntityType,
            LinkType = field.LinkType
        }).ToList();
```

This code should work for you

Comment: Thank you @Arijit Mukherjee, It exactly work as I want....Once again Thank You...

Comment: glad it helped, don't forget to upvote and mark it as solved, if it solved your purpose